# Resources for answering common questions

Tags: discusión, preguntas, recursos

On this Stack Exchange we often get numerous questions of the same type, e.g.

> What is the meaning of this word?

> What is the etymology of this word?

> In what regions is this word used?

These are often answerable using the same resources/references.

**What resources exist for answering common questions on this site?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some resources organised by question type:

| Question | Resources |
| --- | --- |
| What does this word mean? [significado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/significado) [definiciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definiciones) | [Diccionario de la lengua española](https://dle.rae.es/palabra) (DLE) [rae](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rae) Diccionario del uso del español (DUE), María Moliner [SpanishDict](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/palabra) [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/palabra#Spanish) |
| How do I translate this word to/from Spanish? [traducción](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traducci%c3%b3n) | [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/spanish-english/) [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/spanish-english) [SpanishDict](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/palabra) [Wiktionary #Translations](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/word#Translations)* [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?&hl=en#es/en/palabra)* |
| Is there a word for this concept/with this definition? | [Diccionario reverso de la RAE](https://iedra.es/) (IEDRA - formerly DIRAE) <sub>(credit [Chewie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1149/chewie))</sub> |
| How do I correctly use this word in this context? | [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=wordToSearch) (DPD) [rae](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rae) [Diccionario de Dudas y Dificultades de la Lengua Española](https://es.scribd.com/doc/151700987/RAE-Seco-Manuel-Diccionario-de-dudas-y-dificultades-de-la-lengua-espanola) |
| What does this latin-american term mean? What does this word mean in this region of Latin America? [hispanoamérica](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hispanoam%c3%a9rica) [diferencias-regionales](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diferencias-regionales) [méxico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m%c3%a9xico) [argentina](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/argentina) [colombia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colombia) [venezuela](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/venezuela) [chile](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chile) | [Diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=palabra) (DAMER) (2010) [rae](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rae) [Diccionario de anglicismos del español estadounidense](https://www.nhh.no/contentassets/0eec8ce1f2bf4fe2b48d8fd68277fc44/diccionario_anglicismos.pdf) |
| What does this word mean in a legal context? [lenguaje-jurídico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lenguaje-jur%c3%addico) | [Diccionario del español jurídico (DEJ)](https://dej.rae.es/lema/palabra) [rae](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rae) |
| How common is this word in modern Spanish? | [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=palabra&geo=ES) (2004 -) [Corpus de Referencia del Español Actual](http://corpus.rae.es/creanet.html) (CREA) (siglo XI) [rae](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rae) |
| How common is this word historically? When did this word first gain usage? [historia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historia) | [Corpus Diacrónico del Español (CORDE)](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) (siglo X - siglo XX) [rae](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rae) [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=palabra&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=32&smoothing=3) (Spanish corpus (2019)) [Google books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=palabra&lr=lang_es&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X) |
| When did this word first appear in a dictionary? What did this word mean historically? [historia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historia) [diccionarios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diccionarios) [significado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/significado) | [Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico de la lengua española (NTLLE)](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle) (1495 - 1992) [rae](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rae) [Mapa de diccionarios de la RAE](http://web.frl.es/ntllet/SrvltGUILoginNtlletPub) (1780, 1817, 1884, 1925, 1992, 2001 simultáneamenta) [rae](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rae) DLE: [current](https://dle.rae.es/palabra) |
| What is the etymology of this word? [etimología](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etimolog%c3%ada) | [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/palabra#Spanish)* [Wiktionary es](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/palabra#Espa%C3%B1ol)* [Diccionario Etimológico de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?palabra)* [Tesoro de la lengua castellana o española](https://archive.org/details/tesorodelalengua00covauoft/page/n4/mode/2up), Covarrubias (1611) Diccionario crítico etimológico de la lengua castellana, Coromines (1954) Diccionario crítico etimológico castellano e hispánico, Coromines (c.1980) [Breve diccionario etimológico de la lengua castellana](https://archive.org/details/brevediccionario00colo), Coromines (1973) |
| What is the origin/meaning of this idiom? [expresiones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresiones) [modismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modismos) [refranes](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refranes) | Vocabulario de refranes y frases proverbiales, Correas (1627) [Refranes, y modos de hablar castellanos: con los latinos que les corresponden](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PA8JAAAAQAAJ) (1792) [Diccionario de refranes, adagios, proverbios modismos, locuciones y frases proverbiales de la lengua espanola](https://archive.org/details/diccionarioderef01sbaruoft/) (1920) [Diccionario de anécdotas, dichos, ilustraciones, locuciones y refranes](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=25PDT_i0rEQC) [Seniloquium: Refranes que dizen los viejos](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4rIsSFfBAh8C) |
| How do you write this word/punctuation? [ortografía](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ortograf%c3%ada) [puntuación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puntuaci%c3%b3n) | [Ortografía de la lengua española](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/buscar.cgi) (2010) [rae](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rae) [Orthographía española](https://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Ortografia_RAE_1741_reducida.pdf) (1741) [rae](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rae) [Revisions of Spanish orthography / ¿Qué revisiones ha tenido la ortografía española?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/10328/) |
| How is this word pronounced? [pronunciación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciaci%c3%b3n) [fonología](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonolog%c3%ada) | [Wiktionary #Pronunciation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/palabra#Pronunciation_3) Wikipedia: [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Spanish), [AFI](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcripci%C3%B3n_fon%C3%A9tica_del_espa%C3%B1ol_con_el_Alfabeto_Fon%C3%A9tico_Internacional) [forvo.com](https://forvo.com/word/palabra/#es_es) |
| How do I write/use this novel word which is not yet in the dictionary? [neologismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neologismos) [palabras-raras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palabras-raras) | [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/) Twitter: [@RAEinforma](https://twitter.com/raeinforma), [#RAEconsultas](https://twitter.com/hashtag/raeconsultas), [#dudaRAE](https://twitter.com/hashtag/dudaRAE) |
| How does this grammatical rule work? [gramática](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gram%c3%a1tica) | http://www.wikilengua.org [Libro digital Herramientas de español](http://www.bowdoin.edu/hispanic-studies/tools/newgr/ats/) |
| What does this mathematical term mean? [matemáticas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matem%c3%a1ticas) | [Vocabulari de matemàtiques](https://www.ub.edu/ubterm/obra/matematiques/) (en/es/ca) |
| Misc linguistics | https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/ |

* Some results may be unreliable or uncited. Be sure to corroborate claims.

Answer (score 6):

There are often questions about the relationship between words in Spanish and closely related languages, or the etymology of words loaned from other languages. Here is a list of analogues of the RAE/DLE etc in the most common such languages referenced on this site:

#### French [francés](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/franc%c3%a9s)

- [Centre National de Resources Textuelles etc Lexicales](https://www.cnrtl.fr) (CNRTL)
- [Dictionnaire Vivant de la Langue Française](https://dvlf.uchicago.edu) (DVLF)

#### Italian [italiano](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italiano)

- [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/)

#### Catalan [catalán](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catal%c3%a1n)

- [Diccionari de l'Enciclopèdia Catalana](http://www.diccionari.cat/)
- [Diccionari català-valencià-balear](http://dcvb.iecat.net) (DCVB)
- [Diccionari de la llengua catalana de l'Institut d'Estudis Catalans](https://dlc.iec.cat/) (DIEC2)
- [Diccionari de Alguerés](http://www.algueres.net/)
- [L’Atles Lingüístic del Domini Català](http://aldc.espais.iec.cat/) (ALDC)
- [Diccionari de sinònims de frases fetes](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=j3Qp3BoJXq0C)
- [Vocabulari de la llengua catalana medieval](https://www.iec.cat/faraudo/)
- [Phonology Case study: sound patterns in Catalan](https://www.laits.utexas.edu/phonology/catalan/index.html)
- https://www.iec.cat/llengua/recursos.asp

#### Occitan

- [Occitan's automatic translator](http://traductor.gencat.cat) (gencat.cat) (Aranese)
- [Dictionnaire de l'Occitan Médiéval](http://www.dom-en-ligne.de)
- [dicod'Òc](https://www.locongres.org/oc/aplicacions/2014-02-03-16-57-17/dicodoc-recerca)

#### Misc

- [Wiktionary: Translations](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shark#Translations)
- [Wikipedia: Arabic language influence on the Spanish language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_language_influence_on_the_Spanish_language)

---

Other possibilities to add: [portugués](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portugu%c3%a9s), [inglés](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ingl%c3%a9s)

Comment: Poner recursos correspondientes a otras lenguas puede acabar siendo algo larguísimo. Me pregunto: ¿tiene sentido que sea así?

Comment: @Charo he añadido un párrafo aclaratorio - sí, estoy de acuerdo que puede ser demasiado si incluimos muchas lenguas (o muchos recursos por lengua), pero con solo las ~5-6 más influyentes/comunes y un puñado de recursos como máximo no veo problema.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to that the [**English <> Spanish Dictionary**](https://eubd1.ugr.es) of

[image: la Universidad de Granada]