# Why the 1661 Tesoro de la lengua castellana o española, for etymology?

Tags: discusión, recursos

I'm just curious why [this list of "Resources for answering common questions"](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4337) recommends the 1661 Tesoro de la lengua castellana o española for etymology? Is it still accurate, when historical linguistics has improved since 1661?

Comment: ["Sebastián de Covarrubias y las variedades regionales del español. Sobre las precisiones geolingüisticas del *Tesoro de la lengua castellana o española*"](http://descargas.cervantesvirtual.com/servlet/SirveObras/91349429656690619532279/019829.pdf?incr=1)

Answer (score 5):

When researching etymology, it is useful to look at old sources to see how a word and its meaning have evolved over time. For example, if you want to know when a word started to be used in Spanish, a recent dictionary usually does not tell you that. Or if you know the origin of a word, but do not know why is current meaning is so different from its original meaning, such as in [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/37465/24236) about why *rodilla* (knee) comes from Latin *rota* (wheel). So having both recent and old resources is useful for answering questions about etymology.

In addition, unless I am missing something, the two dictionaries you suggest do not provide the etymology of words. While they can be useful to answer some questions, I do not think they should be in the "etymology" section.

Comment: "the two dictionaries you suggest do not provide the etymology of words." You're correct. That's not what I meant.