# Add Cambridge and Collins Dictionaries?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, recursos

What do you think of adding [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/spanish-english/sin-embargo) and [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-spanish/subject) under "How do I translate this word to/from Spanish?" in the Meta question [Resources for answering common questions](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4337/24236)? Were they excluded accidentally or deliberately? What do you think of them?

Comment: Note that the user who compiled the list is active in the site. Also, you can suggest edits yourself. This to say that a more direct approach can also work: _hey X, do you mind if I add this resource?_

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' yes, but that needs to be in the form of a comment then; suggested edits are disabled on Meta posts.

Comment: @Glorfindel the linked question could be made CW so this would be possible.

Comment: There is also the Larousse Spanish<>English dictionaries online.

Answer (score 3):

I have to say that, if the current options are

> - SpanishDict
> - Wiktionary #Translations
> - Google Translate

then, definitely, adding a reputable source like the Cambridge or Collins dictionaries is a **good idea**.

It would also be nice to have an English-Spanish dictionary from a Spanish institution, but I do not seem to find one...

Comment: Perhaps [**English <> Spanish Dictionary**](https://eubd1.ugr.es/) of [la Universidad de Granada](https://ugr.es/)?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps add to that also the [**English <> Spanish Dictionary**](https://eubd1.ugr.es) of the

[image: la Universidad de Granada]